# android LazyList cache issues in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-loadermanager, lazylist

In my app i have a list of items, i'm getting items via LoaderManager. When i select or deselect items it doesn`t work properly, i mean sometimes not select all of them.Maybe it returns cached values to adapter in onLoadFinished method. Does anybody have ideas?

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_mailbox)
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<LazyList<Item>> {


@AfterViews
public void afterViews() {
    broadcastReceiver = new MailboxEmailBroadcastReceiver(this);

    setEmptyText(getString(R.string.fragment_mailbox_list_empty));

    adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getActivity(), mailAccountIdExtra, folderIdExtra);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    setListShown(false);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);        
}

@Override
public Loader<LazyList<Item>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
    ...
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<LazyList<Item>> listLoader, LazyList<Item> items) {
    adapter.swapList(items);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    hideLoader();
    if (isResumed()) {
        setListShown(true);
    } else {
        setListShownNoAnimation(true);
    }
}    

private void selectOrDeselectItems(MenuItem item) {
    adapter.selectAllItems((isSelectAllToggle) ? false : true);        
}
```

}

And here is my adapter.

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

@Override
public View getView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    final Item item = items.get(i);        

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();            
        viewHolder.lineView       = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.line_view);            
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if(item.isChecked()) {
        viewHolder.lineView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else
        viewHolder.lineView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    return convertView;
}


public void swapList(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public List<Item> getList () {
    return items;
}   

public void selectAllItems(boolean isSelectAll) {      
    for (Item item: items) {
        item.setChecked(isSelectAll);            
    }
}


static class ViewHolder {        
    ImageView lineView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Call notifyDataSetChanged after updating items to refresh the view:

```
public void selectAllItems(boolean isSelectAll) {      
    for (Item item: items) {
        item.setChecked(isSelectAll);            
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I`ve already wrote this in onLoadFinished() method. onLoadFinished method is monitoring when object changes.

Comment: Yes, you can do that anywhere, but I recomend to do in the adapter. At the end of any of the methods updating data, so you avoid bugs.